# Multiple selection from Julia array

Tags: julia

In Julia, is there a way to retrieve a vector containing multiple elements from a multi-dimensional array similar to numpy's advanced indexing? For instance from this 2D array:

```
genconv = reshape([6,9,7,1,4,2,3,2,0,9,10,8,7,8,5], 5, 3)
genconv[[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]
```

This results in a 3x3 array, not in a vector:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S21Wv.png)

Comment: don't like it? `[genconv[[1,2,3],[2,3,1]]...]`

Comment: No, cause I'm expecting a vector with three elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get elements by `col` and `row` index one way is to use `sub2ind` function:

`getindex(genconv,sub2ind(size(genconv),[1,2,3],[2,3,1]))`

EDIT

as already @user3580870 has commented

`getindex(genconv,sub2ind(size(genconv),[1,2,3],[2,3,1]))` equals `genconv[sub2ind(size(genconv),[1,2,3],[2,3,1])]`

what I got shows no difference in efficiency between `getindex` and *array comprehensions* syntax.

Comment: a.k.a. `genconv[sub2ind(size(genconv),[1,2,3],[2,3,1])]`

Comment: Cool, works! Coming from python/R this looks unexpectedly complicated. Is this a good choice if I need good performance?

Comment: What about `[genconv[i,j] for (i,j) in zip([1,2,3], [2,3,1])]`? This seems a bit more direct.

Comment: You can also write this as `[genconv[i...] for i in zip([1,2,3], [2,3,1])]` (using splatting), but I actually prefer @jverzani's version as it is clearer.

Comment: FYI, I did some benchmarks in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Gnimuc/2d10aadd4bc765b96056).

Answer (score 4):

Julia 0.5 now supports indexing by arrays of `CartesianIndex`es. A `CartesianIndex` is a special index type that spans multiple dimensions:

```
julia> genconv = reshape([6,9,7,1,4,2,3,2,0,9,10,8,7,8,5], 5, 3)
5×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 6  2  10
 9  3   8
 7  2   7
 1  0   8
 4  9   5

julia> genconv[CartesianIndex(2,3)] # == genconv[2,3]
8
```

What's interesting is that you can use vectors of `CartesianIndex`es to specify this numpy-style pointwise indexing:

```
julia> genconv[[CartesianIndex(1,2),CartesianIndex(2,3),CartesianIndex(3,1)]]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 8
 7
```

That's pretty verbose and terrible-looking, but this can be combined with the new `f.()` special broadcasting syntax for a very nice solution:

```
julia> genconv[CartesianIndex.([1,2,3],[2,3,1])]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 8
 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to just treat the data as a vector, rather than a multidimensional array:

```
genconv = [6,9,7,1,4,2,3,2,0,9,10,8,7,8,5]

genconv[ [10, 13] ]
```